# Notification about already answered chat reply

Tags: bug, chat, notifications, ping

Steps to reproduce:

1. Enter a chat room in a new browser tab.
2. Close the browser tab.
3. Have someone ping you in the room at least twice. (not just once)
4. Open new tab, enter the room again.
5. Even though you were pinged more than once, you will see only "1" in red circle:

   > [image]

If you click the red circle or post something, only the latest ping will be cleared. After clearing the latest ping, reloading will cause the next ping to appear in the red circle, and it can be cleared. Like any uncleared ping, it will cause a notificiation to be sent within 15 minutes.

Can this please be fixed, so that when entering a room where I was pinged multiple times, all pings will be dismissable at once? (this is already the case when not closing the browser tab)

Comment: I experienced it a few times, but I think it takes more time for a message in the chat room to arrive than on the main board or Meta.

Comment: Yes, I know how to reproduce and it's tricky, been planning to post the bug report for a while now. Might edit this instead of posting a new one, stay tuned. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard waiting for notification about edit. :)

Comment: Done, now let's hope it will be fixed.. :)

Comment: @alexolut this seems to be fixed, can you please try to reproduce too?